# SQL Delete Duplicate rows find same text in a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpmyadmin - joomla cms.
i have many articles with a same title. Now I want to delete all those articles having the same title. Please tell me the query how to delete same articles having same title.

I used the command which shows me the count of articles having same title.

```
SELECT 
    title,
    id,
    COUNT(title) 
FROM 
    q3ept_k2_items 
GROUP BY 
    title 
HAVING COUNT(title) > 1
```

Comment: [Have a read here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/139444). It's pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Andrew I think it may take a bit more effort than "how to delete".  In this case the requirement is to remove entries other than min(id), I assume.   Also, Microsoft sql site - some syntax may not apply.

Comment: can you suggest me a query regarding my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

For keep lowest id value,

```
DELETE item1 FROM q3ept_k2_items item1, q3ept_k2_items item2 WHERE item1.id > item2.id AND item1.title = item2.title
```

For keep highest id value,

```
DELETE item1 FROM q3ept_k2_items item1, q3ept_k2_items item2 WHERE item1.id < item2.id AND item1.title = item2.title
```

If you want to improve a little bit performance, you can change this style,

```
WHERE item1.title = item2.title AND item1.id > item2.id
```

or

```
WHERE item1.title = item2.title AND item1.id < item2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT title INTO temp FROM q3ept_k2_items;

DROP TABLE q3ept_k2_items;

RENAME TABLE temp TO q3ept_k2_items;
```

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: @KhanBaba You should never copy & paste answer into live mysql data without taking a backup first, And yes the query uses WHERE IN which means the subquery should return 1 column instead of 3 And I still think the query is wrong (it will delete all duplicates without leaving any copy).

Comment: @ahmad thanks for your advice i have a copy of my database. yeah there is some mistake because it will delete all articles having same titles.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table where title not in (select distinct(title) from table)
```

Comment: Receiving an error -  #1093 - You can't specify target table 'q3ept_content' for update in FROM clause

Comment: can u please post the full query what u entered

Comment: Column :   Title
 i want to delete all articles having same title  and one articles count should be lift.